# DataGridRow Cells property

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight, properties

I would like to get to DataGridRow Cells property. It's a table of cells in a current DataGrid. But I cannot get access direct from code nor by Reflection:

```
var x = dataGridRow.GetType().GetProperty("Cells") //returns null
```

Is there any way to get this table?

And related question - in Watch window (VS2008) regular properties have an icon of a hand pointing on a sheet of paper. But DataGridRow.Cells has an icon of a hand pointing on a sheet of paper with a little yellow envelope in a left bottom corner - what does it mean?

Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 3):

You can get any Cell by its index if you know DataGrid name:

```
DataGridCell cell = dataGridName.Columns[columnIndex].GetCellContent(e.Row).Parent as DataGridCell;
```

Comment: Thank you, Telerik's grid has Cells propery, for sdk's datagrid its ok by this also.

Answer (score 0):

The Cells property is internal to the assembly hence you can't access it from code.

Comment: and there isn't a way to manipulate them from the code expect in the events?